# How to find non-zero integers in a list containing zeros and times?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have lists like `{0, 1, 0, 3, 0, -t2, 0, -(1/t2), 0, 0, 0, 0}` including zeros, non-zero integers, and times. I wonder how I get the position of all non-zero integers?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have tried this method, which I saw from another post. But this method includes all the Times terms.

Comment: `Position[list, n_Integer /; n != 0]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not working either. This one gave very weird results for Times.

Comment: Forgot the level spec `1`.

Comment: Can `t2` be zero?

Comment: The original example of lists could be confusing, so I just edited it. The lists are like `{0, 1, 0, 3, 0, -t2, 0, -(1/t2), 0, 0, 0, 0}`. What I want is the position of `1` and `3`.

Comment: @Syed For my data, `t2` cannot be zero. These are indeterminate variables, which are saved as `Times` or possibly `symbol`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It works after adding the level spec `1`. Thank you so much! Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I can accept it? Also, a possible explanation would be very appreciated. I am very new to Mathematica.

Comment: `Position[expr, pattern, 1]` returns the positions of the elements of `expr` at level 1 that match `pattern`.  The pattern `n_Integer /; n != 0` matches integers that are nonzero.  The elements of `expr` are scanned left to right.  The named pattern `n_Integer` will match each integer at level 1 and assign the value to the symbol `n`; then, in the condition (`\;`), the symbol `n` in `n != 0` corresponds to the matched integer; if `n` is nonzero, the condition evaluates to `True` and the integer `n` is considered to match the whole `pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

Position[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -t2, 0, -(1/t2), 0, 0, 0, 0}, n_ /; n =!= 0,
1] // Rest

Comment: This gives the position of both integers and times. But I only want the position of integers. I just edited my post since the original example could be confusing. The lists are `{0, 1, 0, 3, 0, -t2, 0, -(1/t2), 0, 0, 0, 0}`. What I want is the position of `1` and `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Position[{0, 1, 0, 3, 0, -t2, 0, -(1/t2), 0, 0, 0, 0},
n_Integer /; n != 0, 1]

This gives the following output: {{2}, {4}}

Which says that at positions 2 and 4 there are integers that are not 0. At positions 2 and 4 are the values 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks. Refs: [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257492/how-to-find-non-zero-integers-in-a-list-containing-zeros-and-times#comment642103_257492), [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257492/how-to-find-non-zero-integers-in-a-list-containing-zeros-and-times#comment642108_257492).